# How to preserve information when failing?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

I'm writing some code that uses the `StateT` monad transformer to keep track of some stateful information (logging and more).

The monad I'm passing to `StateT` is very simple:

```
data CheckerError a = Bad {errorMessage :: Log} | Good a
    deriving (Eq, Show)


instance Monad CheckerError where
    return x = Good x

    fail msg = Bad msg

    (Bad msg) >>= f = Bad msg
    (Good x) >>= f = f x

type CheckerMonad a = StateT CheckerState CheckerError a
```

It's just a `Left` and `Right` variant.

What troubles me is the definition of `fail`. In my computation I produce a lot of information inside this monad and I'd like to keep this information even when failing. 
Currently the only thing I can do is to convert everything to a `String` and create a `Bad` instance with the `String` passed as argument to `fail`.

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
fail msg = do
    info <- getInfoOutOfTheComputation
    return $ Bad info
```

However everything I tried until now gives type errors, probably because this would mix different monads.

Is there anyway in which I can implement `fail` in order to preserve the information I need without having to convert all of it into a `String`?

I cannot believe that the best Haskell can achieve is using `show`+`read` to pass all the information as the string to `fail`.

Comment: Short answer: That's not what `fail` is for, so of course it doesn't work.

Comment: @Carl Then show me how I should achieve this. What I want: 1) a way to "stop" the computation when something bad happens 2) preserve the stateful information produced up to that point. All the examples I've seen that are able to achieve 1 use `fail` and fail to achieve number 2. Currently the only thing I came up is: `prettyFail = do state <- get; fail $ show state` implementing `Show` and `Read` in all state information, which I don't think is an elegant solution (although it works perfectly well).

Comment: `fail` is only intended as a stopgap measure to support pattern match failures in do-notation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `CheckerError` monad is very similar to the `Either` monad. I will use the `Either` monad (and its monad transformer counterpart [`ErrorT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.3.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html#t%3aErrorT)) in my answer.

There is a subtlety with monad trasformers: order matters. Effects in the "inner" monad have primacy over effects caused by the "outer" layers. Consider these two alternative definitions of `CheckerMonad`:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Error

type CheckerState = Int     -- dummy definitions for convenience
type CheckerError = String

type CheckerMonad a = StateT CheckerState (Either String) a

type CheckerMonad' a = ErrorT String (State CheckerState) a
```

In `CheckerMonad`, `Either` is the inner monad, and this means a failure will wipe the whole state. Notice the type of this run function:

```
runCM :: CheckerMonad a -> CheckerState -> Either CheckerError (a,CheckerState)
runCM m s = runStateT m s
```

You either fail, or return a result along with the state up to that point.

In  `CheckerMonad'`, `State` is the inner monad. This means the state will be preserved even in case of failures:

```
runCM' :: CheckerMonad' a -> CheckerState -> (Either CheckerError a,CheckerState)
runCM' m s = runState (runErrorT m) s
```

A pair is returned, which contains the state up to that point, and either a failure or a result.

It takes a bit of practice to develop an intuition of how to properly order monad transformers. The chart in the [Type juggling](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers#Type_juggling) section of [this Wikibook page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers) is a good starting point.

Also, it is better to avoid using [`fail`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v%3afail) directly, because it is considered a bit of a wart in the language. Instead, use the specialized functions for throwing errors provided by the error transformer.  When working with `ErrorT` or some other instance of [`MonadError`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.3.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html#t%3aMonadError), use [throwError](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Error.html#v%3athrowError).

```
sillycomp :: CheckerMonad' Bool
sillycomp = do
    modify (+1)
    s <- get 
    if s == 3
        then throwError "boo"
        else return True

*Main> runCM' sillycomp 2
Loading package transformers-0.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package mtl-2.1.2 ... linking ... done.
(Left "boo",3)

*Main> runCM' sillycomp 3
(Right True,4)
```

`ErrorT` is sometimes annoying to use because, unlike `Either`, it requires an [`Error`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.3.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html#t%3aError) constraint on the error type. The `Error` typeclass forces you to define two error constructors `noMsg` and `strMsg`, which may or may not make sense for your type.

You can use [`EitherT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/either-4.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Either.html) from the [`either`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/either) package instead, which lets you use any type whatsoever as the error. When working with [`EitherT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/either-4.1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Either.html#t%3aEitherT), use the `left` function to throw errors.