# Transforming a Monad to trace failure in recursive monadic code

Tags: debugging, haskell, trace

I have a longish recursive function with many cases for all of the different data forms it can operate on. The return type of the function is a `Maybe`, where `Nothing` represents failure. The recursive call fails if any of its subcalls fail, so the computation in each case of the function is done in a do block.

The implementation I have so far is definitely buggy, because I'm giving it input that should succeed, and it is failing, i.e. evaluating to `Nothing`. However, I cannot determine which subcall is evaluating to `Nothing`. To try to pinpoint where this happens, I want to trace all of the recursive calls. I had the idea that if I could insert a `trace` call into `Maybe`'s `bind` (that is, `(>>=)`), I wouldn't have to insert `trace` into all of the cases of the function.

To implement this idea, I just copied the implementation of the `Maybe` type along with its `Monad` instance and modified it as I described: I inserted calls to `trace` in the bind function.

```
data TraceMaybe a =  TNothing | TJust a
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

tracet :: TraceMaybe a -> TraceMaybe a
tracet TNothing = trace "monad failed" TNothing
tracet x        = trace "monad good" x

instance  Monad TraceMaybe  where
    (TJust x) >>= k = tracet $ k x
    TNothing  >>= _ = TNothing
    (TJust _) >>  k = tracet k
    TNothing  >>  _ = TNothing
    return          = TJust
    fail m          = TNothing
```

Then I was mostly able to just change the return type of the big function, although I had to change some things where my code assumed that the `Monad` was actually `Maybe` (`catMaybes`, for example),

My question is this: is there a more elegant, compositional way to create an only slightly modified version of Maybe? I've heard of "`Monad` transformers", but the examples I've seen don't seem entirely relevant.

I wonder if there is some way to combine Writer and Maybe to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can combine `Writer` and `Maybe` to solve your problem.

With monad transformers, order often matters. Which should be the base monad, and which the transformer? Here it is `Writer` the one that should be the base monad, because otherwise a failure would wipe out the log (see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127973/how-to-preserve-information-when-failing/23128898#23128898)).

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Writer.Strict
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

computation :: Int -> MaybeT (Writer [String]) Int
computation i = do
    foo <- return 5  
    lift $ tell ["This is a log message"]
    if i == 3
        then mzero -- from MonadPlus, of which MaybeT is an instance
        else return $ i + foo 

*Main> runWriter . runMaybeT $ computation 3
(Nothing,["This is a log message"])

*Main> runWriter . runMaybeT $ computation 2
(Just 7,["This is a log message"])
```

A good introduction to transformers is the paper ["Monad Transformers Step by Step"](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~wh5a/personal/Transformers.pdf).

The `mtl` package has typeclasses that let you avoid sprinkling your code with `lift`s in many cases, and also let you write more generic signatures (saying "the monad should have `MonadWriter` capabilities" instead of having to specify the exact monad stack).

```
computation' :: (MonadWriter [String] m) => Int -> MaybeT m Int
computation' i = do
    foo <- return 5  
    tell ["This is a log message"] -- no explicit lift
    if i == 3
        then mzero     
        else return $ i + foo
```

When the number of log messages grows, using lists as the monoid user by `Writer` becomes inefficient because the append function is costly. You can turn to structures with more efficient append, like [`dlist`s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist).

Sometimes `Writer` is inconvenient because you only have access to the log messages at the *end* of the computation. You can use streaming monad transformers like the ones in the `conduit` or `pipes` packages to be able to log messages in the middle of the computation, without forcing your monad to live in `IO`.

Comment: `if cond then mzero else ...` is equivalent to `guard (not cond); ...`.